# Write UTF-8 files from R

Tags: windows, r, unicode, utf-8

Whereas R seems to handle Unicode characters well internally, I'm not able to output a data frame in R with such UTF-8 Unicode characters. Is there any way to force this?

```
data.frame(c("hīersumian","ǣmettigan"))->test
write.table(test,"test.txt",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

The output text file reads:

`hiersumian <U+01E3>mettigan`

I am using R version 3.0.2 in a Windows environment (Windows 7).

**EDIT**

---

It's been suggested in the answers that R is writing the file correctly in UTF-8, and that the problem lies with the software I'm using to view the file. Here's some code where I'm doing everything in R. I'm reading in a text file encoded in UTF-8, and R reads it correctly. Then R writes the file out in UTF-8 and reads it back in again, and now the correct Unicode characters are gone.

```
read.table("myinputfile.txt",encoding="UTF-8")->myinputfile
myinputfile[1,1]
write.table(myinputfile,"myoutputfile.txt",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
read.table("myoutputfile.txt",encoding="UTF-8")->myoutputfile
myoutputfile[1,1]
```

Console output:

```
> read.table("myinputfile.txt",encoding="UTF-8")->myinputfile
> myinputfile[1,1]
[1] hīersumian
Levels: hīersumian ǣmettigan
> write.table(myinputfile,"myoutputfile.txt",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
> read.table("myoutputfile.txt",encoding="UTF-8")->myoutputfile
> myoutputfile[1,1]
[1] <U+FEFF>hiersumian
Levels: <U+01E3>mettigan <U+FEFF>hiersumian
>
```

Comment: works for me (R-devel on Ubuntu 12.04) when viewing the file in the terminal, vi, or emacs.

Comment: @BenBolker Does this mean that this problem is specific to the Windows version of R?

Comment: To clarify: this is a Windows-specific problem. On OS X the result is verifiably correct. `file test.txt` replies with `test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text`. A hexdump shows the correct bytes. Well-written question though.

Comment: Isn't it more correct to say that this is a problem specific to the R version for Windows (R exists in different versions depending on the OS)? I don't have any problems with using UTF-8 and Unicode in Windows otherwise, so I doubt the problem lies with Windows.

Comment: I've submitted a request to the R-devel mailing list for UTF-8 to be properly supported in future versions of R for Windows.

Comment: Now that you got a chilly response on r-devel (http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/34861), I wonder if answers here could focus on workarounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 file output in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675360/utf-8-file-output-in-r)

Answer (score 14):

This "answer" serves rather the purpose of clarifying that there is something odd going on behind the scenes:

"hīersumian" doesn't even make it into the data frame it seems. The "ī"-symbol is in all cases converted to "i".

```
options("encoding" = "native.enc")
t1 <- data.frame(a = "hīersumian ")
t1
#             a
# 1 hiersumian 

options("encoding" = "UTF-8")
t1 <- data.frame(a = "hīersumian ")
t1
#             a
# 1 hiersumian 

options("encoding" = "UTF-16")
t1 <- data.frame(a = "hīersumian ")
t1
#             a
# 1 hiersumian
```

The following sequence successfully writes "ǣmettigan" to the text file:

```
t2 <- data.frame(a = "ǣmettigan")

getOption("encoding")
# [1] "native.enc"

Encoding(t2[,"a"]) <- "UTF-16"

write.table(t2,"test.txt",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F)
```

[image]

It is not going to work with "encoding" as "UTF-8" or "UTF-16" and also specifying "fileEncoding" will either lead to a defect or no output.

Somewhat disappointing as so far I managed to get all Unicode issues fixed somehow.

Comment: While `write.table` still appears to fail on my machine (Ubuntu), the automatic conversion of `"hīersumian"` no longer seems to be an issue in my current version of R (3.3.2)

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something OS-specific, but `data.table` appears to have no problem with this (or perhaps more likely it's an update to R internals since this question was originally posed):

```r
t1 = data.table(a = c("hīersumian", "ǣmettigan"))
tmp = tempfile()
fwrite(t1, tmp)
system2('cat', tmp)
# a
# hīersumian
# ǣmettigan
fread(tmp)
#             a
# 1: hīersumian
# 2:  ǣmettigan
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post that basically says its windows way of encoding text. Lots more detail in post. User should write the file in binary using

writeBin(charToRaw(x), con, endian="little")

https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to write an Excel file with the `write.xlsx` function from the `openxlsx` package

```r
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(data.frame(a = "hīersumian"), "test.xlsx")
```

[image]