# How do I fix problems with letters from a different alphabet on R?

Tags: r, letter, alphabet

When I first wrote my script, letters such as 'ç' and 'ã - very commonly used in portuguese - were fine. So if I wrote, for example, the word 'vagão' in portuguese, that's how it would read it. But when I reopened the project with that script, it reads "vagÃ£o". How do I fix it?

Comment: Look at `encoding` and probably `locale` settings?

Comment: You're right! File -> Reopen with encoding -> UTF-8 does the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking at encoding issues or conversion issues due to encoding on Windows(assuming that you're using windows). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622589/17017832) might give you your answer.