# How to change letters in different locale?

Tags: r, text, character-encoding, locale

I read HTML text with the following command:
 `text <- read_html("linkoftext")`
The result is:

```
"Veri analizi, farklı iş, bilim ve sosyal bilim alanlarında çeşitli isimler altında çeşitli teknikleri kapsayan çok yönlü ve farklı yaklaşımlara sahiptir. Veri entegrasyonu veri analizinin öncüsüdür."
```

This text includes letters like "ş ç ü ö ı". I need to substitute them to "s c u o i". I wrote the following code:

```
string <- "ş ç ı ğ ü ö f s x q"
chartr("ş ç ı ğ ü ö", "s c i g u o", string)
```

How can apply the code above to my text, since I have still these letters as the output of `chartr`?

Comment: add an example of `text` to your question.

Comment: It is an html text file. I have taken it like that `text<- read_html("linkoftext").` if you are asking to see how it is look like >> `"Veri analizi, farklı iş, bilim ve sosyal bilim alanlarında çeşitli isimler altında çeşitli teknikleri kapsayan çok yönlü ve farklı yaklaşımlara sahiptir.
Veri entegrasyonu veri analizinin öncüsüdür."`   As you see from here, I need to change some letters, because R do not recognize them.

Comment: **I dont see here** that you have to change some letters because R does not recognize.

Comment: Okay, better to say, when I try to create a word cloud of this text, I can not see these letters in the word cloud. For example;  ü seen as something like " t' ". I mean it changes these letters with different 'letters'. So my wordcloud seem meaningless.

Comment: I believe it has something to to with [TEXT ENCODING](https://www.google.de/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBD_deDE736DE736&ei=BwGqW_6bCo_isAertKSIAQ&q=r+text+encoding+stackoverflow&oq=r+text+encoding+stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1j33i10k1.3351.5974.0.6087.14.12.0.0.0.0.316.1612.0j6j2j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.9.1606...33i22i29i30k1j33i13i21k1.0.klHUj6YE2c4)

Comment: I found the solution from here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944331/keeping-turkish-characters-with-the-text-mining-package-for-r` . Thank you.

Comment: @SBA, you can post the answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your locale setting is different from native, i.e. Turkish. So to change locale you can use `Sys.setlocale` function, please see the code below:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Turkish") # switch to Turkish locale
string <- "ş ç ı ğ ü ö f s x q"
string
# [1] "ş ç ı ğ ü ö f s x q"

chartr("şçığüö", "sciguo", string)
# [1] "s c i g u o f s x q"

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "") # switch to native locale
```