# Converting XML with Japanese characters into CSV using R

Tags: r, xml, csv, scripting

I have few XML files which are having Japanese characters, when I change it to csv it's japanese characters changed to code point e.g. `<U+FA32>` some characters like this. 
I want to keep them as it is and change it to csv or excel format.
I tried changing Locale, I tried changing setting of R studio. Nothing is working. The xml contains a lot of data and some fields are having email body which consists raw data with some special characters. 
Let me show you how my code for changing xml to csv looks like:-

```
for(f in file)
{
  doc <- xmlParse(f,useInternalNodes = TRUE , fileEncoding='UTF-8');
  xL <- xmlToList(doc, fileEncoding='UTF-8');
  data <- ldply(xL, data.frame, fileEncoding='UTF-8');
  write.csv(data, concat(f,".csv"), row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding='UTF-8')

}
```

Please help with the solution. If we can change it to csv even with some other ways than R please help.

Comment: Is the xml file encoded in utf-8?

Comment: yes it is encoded in utf-8

Comment: @kennyzx can you help me?

Comment: I don’t know R, and don’t have the xml files to figure out what is the problem. But can you try online xml to csv converters? They are free and tested.

Comment: file is big. It's size is more than 100 MB. It can't get converted. Still let me try again.

Comment: Are you using windows? Writing UTF-8 on Windows with R is notoriously difficult.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675360/utf-8-file-output-in-r help?

Comment: No it did not help

Comment: Here some background information: http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2018/02/21/string-encoding-and-r/. Without a sample file and a windows machine with the same locale as you (which one?), I cannot help any further, though.